# How to get the width of an element where the overflow is hidden?

Tags: javascript, overflow

I have a button element with a span element inside it and I need to be able to obtain the actual width of the span.

```
<button id="button"><span>text that is longer than the button width</span></button>
```

None of the methods I have tried are showing the true width (which is the JSFiddle example is about 233px - this can been seen by simply removing the overflow:hidden css property from the span):

https://jsfiddle.net/teatnmza/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual* width of the span is the same as the button, because you have hidden any overflow.

I think you need you need to get the scroll width of the span, and in fact you are nearly there:

```
$("button span")[0].scrollWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("button span")[0].scrollWidth  // returns 231
```

See **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teatnmza/2/)**

Edit: Didn't saw that George got that first, so credits must go to him.